# localstorage is displaying everything together?

Tags: javascript, local-storage

[image]

Hey guys,

just playing around with localstorage here. Ran in to an issue and I'm not sure why it's doing that exactly. before concatenating the strings in function 'saveTo'

I'd appreciate the help.

```
const saveTo = () => {

    localStorage.setItem('textinput',firstName.textContent + lastName.textContent + inputEmail.textContent)
    
}
```

I had it like this

```
  const saveTo = () => {
    
        localStorage.setItem('textinput',firstName.textContent)
        localStorage.setItem('textinput',lastName.textContent)
        localStorage.setItem('textinput',inputEmail.textContent)

    }
```

But, even then. Only the first name would dsiplay in all three fields. The email never shows.

html

```
  <form id="form" action="">
        <input type="text" placeholder="first name" class="inputone" >
        <input type="text" placeholder="last name" class="inputtwo" >
        <input type="email" placeholder="email" class="email" >
        <button type="submit" class="save" >save</button>
    </form>

<Table class="table-data" >
    <tr>
        <td class="tablefirstname" >hey</td>
        <td class="tablelastname" >hey</td>
        <td class="tableemail" >hey</td>
    </tr>
</Table>
```

javascript

```
//table
const firstName = document.querySelector('.tablefirstname');
const lastName = document.querySelector('.tablelastname');
const inputEmail = document.querySelector('.tableemail');


//form

const inputFirst = document.querySelector('.inputone');
const inputSecond = document.querySelector('.inputtwo');
const email = document.querySelector('.email');

const button = document.querySelector('.save');

//adding to storage
const storedInput = localStorage.getItem('textinput');


//if statement for storage 

if (storedInput) {
    firstName.textContent = storedInput;
    lastName.textContent = storedInput;
    inputEmail.textContent = storedInput;
}

//event listeners 




inputFirst.addEventListener('input', letter => {
    
    firstName.textContent = letter.target.value
   
})


inputSecond.addEventListener('input', extra => {
    
    lastName.textContent = extra.target.value
   
})

inputEmail.addEventListener('input', mail => {
    
    inputEmail.textContent = mail.target.value
   
})

button.addEventListener('click', saveTo)


// function for saving

const saveTo = () => {

    localStorage.setItem('textinput',firstName.textContent + lastName.textContent + inputEmail.textContent)
    
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `textContent` and not `value`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no you have to use JSON [parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) / [stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

```
// save to localeStorage
let obj = {}
  obj.firstName  = firstName.value
  obj.lastName   = lastName.value
  obj.inputEmail = inputEmail.value

//verify:
console.log( 'obj=', JSON.stringify(obj) )


localStorage.setItem('textinput', JSON.stringify(obj))
```

```js
//read localeStorage
let obj = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('textinput'))
firstName.value  = obj.firstName 
lastName.value   = obj.lastName
inputEmail.value = obj.inputEmail
```

complete example of use

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>  <meta charset="UTF-8"> </head>
<body>

<form id="myForm" action="">
  <input type="text"   placeholder="first name" name="inputone" >
  <input type="text"   placeholder="last name"  name="inputtwo" >
  <input type="email"  placeholder="email"     name="email" >
  <button type="submit" >save</button>
</form>

<script>

myForm = document.querySelector('#myForm');

// init
// get form inputs from Local Storage
let objLS = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('textinput') || '{}')
// set localeStorage values to the form elements
Object.entries(objLS).forEach(([name,txt])=>myForm[name].value = txt)

myForm.onsubmit = evt => // your save button
  {
  evt.preventDefault() // disable submit  & page reload

  let formInputs = Object.fromEntries(new FormData(myForm).entries()) 
  //console.log( formInputs )

  // save values to LocalStorage
  localStorage.setItem('textinput', JSON.stringify(formInputs))
  }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where exactly would i be putting that? i thought stringify was for numbers only?

Comment: doesnt work - displays like this ShariqAhmedShariqAhmedShariqAhmedShariqAhmedshariqahmed
ShariqAhmedShariqAhmedShariqAhmedShariqAhmedshariqahmed
ShariqAhmedShariqAhmedShariqAhmedShariqAhmedshariqahmed

Comment: @shar27 you have certanliy missing something, please show me the console.log I have added

Comment: @shar27 see again my answer with a complete HTML example

Comment: @shar27 I found your error, you do `firstName.textContent` instead of  `firstName.value`

Comment: I will try this

Comment: .value gives me NaN for all, there is nothing in the console. it's quite strange

Comment: @shar27 .in which line of my code? NaN stand for numeric values, and there is no numeric operation in!

Comment: i only used this I found your error, you do firstName.textContent instead of firstName.value. I didn't use yours as it i didn't find it helpful for my own learning journey. However, I would love it if you could share some docs that would help me to write what you did.

Comment: that ? [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) &
[Object.fromEntries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries)

Answer (score 1):

You need to save items to localstorage as an json string instead of a normal string

Modify your `saveTo` function as follows

```
    //table
const firstName = document.querySelector('.tablefirstname');
const lastName = document.querySelector('.tablelastname');
const inputEmail = document.querySelector('.tableemail');


//form

const inputFirst = document.querySelector('.inputone');
const inputSecond = document.querySelector('.inputtwo');
const email = document.querySelector('.email');

const button = document.querySelector('.save');

//adding to storage
let storedInput;
try{
  storedInput = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('textinput'));
}
catch(e) {
  console.log("Error parsing data: " + localStorage.getItem('textinput'));
  console.log("Error: ", e)
}


//if statement for storage 

if (storedInput) {
    firstName.textContent = storedInput.firstName;
    lastName.textContent = storedInput.lastName;
    inputEmail.textContent = storedInput.inputEmail;
}

//event listeners 




inputFirst.addEventListener('input', letter => {
    
    firstName.textContent = letter.target.value
   
})


inputSecond.addEventListener('input', extra => {
    
    lastName.textContent = extra.target.value
   
})

inputEmail.addEventListener('input', mail => {
    
    inputEmail.textContent = mail.target.value
   
})


// function for saving

const saveTo = () => {  

  localStorage.setItem('textinput',JSON.stringify({firstName: 
    firstName.textContent, lastName: lastName.textContent, inputEmail: 
    inputEmail.textContent}))

}

button.addEventListener('click', saveTo)
```

Comment: this didn't work, it displays like this and does the same in the localstorage. ShariqAhmedShariqAhmedShariqAhmedShariqAhmedshariqahmed
ShariqAhmedShariqAhmedShariqAhmedShariqAhmedshariqahmed
ShariqAhmedShariqAhmedShariqAhmedShariqAhmedshariqahmed

Comment: and still no email

Comment: I have edited my answer. You can try it using https://jsfiddle.net/the_vv/tzLpweb3/